# Probability that two numbers differ by one bit

Tags: probability, combinatorics, binary

Assuming that *t* is the bit length of the numbers and that we can pick 2 random numbers (the same number cannot be chosen twice), which is the probability that the two numbers will differ by exactly one bit?

From my understanding, the probability to hit a specific bit pattern is $$\frac{1}{2^t}$$

Since there are only *t - 1* other bit patterns which differs from the first one by one bit, then we have that the probability to hit two numbers which differ by one bit is:

$$\frac{1}{2^t}\frac{t-1}{2^t} = \frac{t-1}{2^{2t}}$$

Does this make sense?

Thanks

Comment: Are there not $t$ bit patterns that differ by one bit? Each of the $t$ bits can be changed.

Comment: Are the random numbers distinct (chosen without replacement), or could the same number be chosen twice (chosen with replacement)?

Comment: No, the same number cannot be chosen twice (chosen without replacement).

Comment: Okay, it would be nice to clarify that in the question (I have amended my answer to handle both cases). In any case, my first comment still applies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exclusive-or of two $n$-bit patterns that differ by $k$ bits is an $n$-bit pattern with $k$ ones and $n-k$ zeros. Thus, after choosing the first $n$-bit pattern, there are $\binom{n}{k}$ patterns which differ by $k$ bits.

---

**With Replacement**

Since there are $2^n$ different $n$-bit patterns, the probability that two $n$-bit patterns differ by $k$ bits is
$$
\frac{\binom{n}{k}}{2^n}
$$
Therefore, the probability that they differ by $1$ bit is
$$
\frac{n}{2^n}
$$

---

**Without Replacement**

Without replacement, the case of $k=0$ is not included, thus, the probability that two $n$-bit patterns differ by $k$ bits is
$$
\frac{\binom{n}{k}[k\ne0]}{2^n-1}
$$
where $[\cdots]$ are [Iverson Brackets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket).

Therefore, the probability that they differ by $1$ bit is
$$
\frac{n}{2^n-1}
$$

Comment: Then me and the other guy must have a mistake somewhere in each of our answers. Can you please point it out?

Comment: @barak, I think you are assuming that the two picked numbers are different, while robjohn is not making that assumption. The question says, "we pick two random numbers". Only OP knows whether the two numbers are guaranteed to be different.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Good point. I was not assuming that the two random numbers were distinct. I have left a comment for the OP.

Comment: When the question says "we can pick 2 random numbers", why should we interpret it as two *distinct* random numbers ? I agree with your interpretation.

Comment: @trueblueanil: unfortunately, the OP has replied to my comment and they intended for the choice to be made without replacement.

Comment: @robjohn: Doesn't "`without replacement`" mean that the numbers **ARE** distinct?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I see you've updated this case in your answer... Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are $2^t$ possibilities. 
The favorable cases are when only one bit is different. For the first time it doesn't matter, what you choose. For the second time this one different bit can be located on $t$ different places, if $t$ is the length. 
So the probability is: $$\frac{t}{2^t-1}$$
$2^t-1$ because after you choose the first number, after that you have one less.

Answer (score 0):

For every value, there are $t$ values different by one bit

Since there are $2^t$ values, there are seemingly $2^t\cdot{t}$ such pairs

But we need to divide this number by $2$ in order to eliminate duplicates

So the total number of pairs differing by one bit is $\dfrac{2^t\cdot{t}}{2}=\color\red{2^{t-1}\cdot{t}}$

The total number of pairs is $\dbinom{2^t}{2}=\dfrac{2^t\cdot(2^t-1)}{2}=\color\green{(2^{t-1})\cdot(2^t-1)}$

Hence the probability of choosing a pair differing by one bit is $\dfrac{\color\red{2^{t-1}\cdot{t}}}{\color\green{(2^{t-1})\cdot(2^t-1)}}=\dfrac{{t}}{2^t-1}$